# jQuery invoice calculations for items and totals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript.

Current issues I'm facing:

1. When you add a new row it's adding the row (great!) however the first new one added works fine, applies _0 at the end of the name / id however when you add more it does not do _1, _2 etc.. but instead _1_1, _2_2_2, _3_3_3_3 - any ideas how I can fix that?
2. I need to calculate the sub total and totals from figures added on the invoice items, like price, qty, discount (figure or %) sub-total and then overall from everything at bottom. The VAT is set as a variable in PHP at the moment for example define('VAT_RATE','20') which would be 20%

**UPDATE**

I have attempted to start it, getting NaN though and its only taking anything with a class="calculate" and adding to sub-total but it's a start I guess. I added qty but does not seem to play ball, vat and total I have not added.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/morgjvg6/4/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // copy customer details to shipping
    $('input.copy-input').on("change keyup paste", function () {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
        $('input#' + thisID + "_ship").val($(this).val());
    });

    // add new product row on invoice
    $(".add-row").click(function () {
        $("#invoice_table").each(function () {
            var tds = '<tr>';
            jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function (index, element) {
                var html = $(this).html().replace(/invoice_product/g, 'invoice_product_' + index)
                    .replace(/invoice_product_desc/g, 'invoice_product_desc_' + index)
                    .replace(/invoice_product_qty/g, 'invoice_product_qty_' + index)
                    .replace(/invoice_product_price/g, 'invoice_product_price_' + index)
                    .replace(/invoice_product_sub/g, 'invoice_product_sub_' + index);
                tds += '<td>' + html + '</td>';
            });
            tds += '</tr>';
            if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
                $('tbody', this).append(tds);
            } else {
                $(this).append(tds);
            }
        });

        return false
    });

// Adding the change events for the Price and 
// quantity fields only..
// Changing the total should not affect anything
calculateTotal();

$('.calculate').on('change keyup paste', function() {
    updateTotals(this);
    calculateTotal();
});

function updateTotals(elem) {
    // This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed
    var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();
    var quantity = $container.find('.calculate-qty').val();
    var price = $container.find('.calculate').val();
    var subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    $container.find('.calculate-sub').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
}

function calculateTotal(){
  // This will Itearate thru the subtotals and 
    // claculate the grandTotal and Quantity here

    var lineTotals = $('.calculate-sub');
    var grandTotal = 0.0;
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    $.each(lineTotals, function(i){
        grandTotal += parseFloat($(lineTotals[i]).text()) ;
    });

    $('.invoice-sub-total').text(parseFloat(grandTotal ).toFixed(2) );  
}

});
```

Comment: here is the answer to your first question: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stt6q296/1/). Is that what you need?

Comment: Yep almost! the numbering is working great but its updating them all as invoice_product_1 for each and every name / id and replacing others like invoice_product_desc - so not doing for them all but replacing them all with same name if that makes sense. Thanks for your help, any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Any ideas? sorry to be a pain on a right deadline :)

Comment: can you change `flag` to `index` in your regex, and see if it does the job ?

Comment: 1 sec, will try that now. thanks mate

Comment: did not do the trick, shall i update your fiddle with latest on everything?

Comment: Just updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/stt6q296/3/

Comment: i am not getting what you want as your output, If you can explain me briefly i will try to help.

Comment: So i have 5 inputs for example: invoice_product, invoice_product_desc, invoice_product_qty etc.. when i add a new row i just need them to apply a new index to the end of those that were replicated on that new row so... invoice_product_1, invoice_product_desc_1, invoice_product_qty_1, next row invoice_product_2, invoice_product_desc_2, invoice_product_qty_2 etc... does that make sense?

Comment: how about this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stt6q296/4/) ?

Comment: It still seems to be setting everything as invoice_product for all of them :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have to use event delegation for input fields that were created dynamically:

```
// delegate events on #invoice_table:
$('#invoice_table').on('change keyup paste', '.calculate', function() {
    updateTotals(this);
    calculateTotal();
});
```

Next thing is that you used `.text()` to update input field:

```
$container.find('.calculate-sub').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
```

while you should use `.val()` :

```
$container.find('.calculate-sub').val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
```

The same in `calculateTotal()` method, where you should also use `.val()`.

Next, this part is unnecesary :

```
$("#invoice_table").each(function () {
```

since you have only one table (and only one element in DOM can have that `id`).

Finaly, I would not use `id` attributes, and give array names for input fields. That way you don't have to play with `.replace()` and you can easily send all the values to your back-end app as arrays.

Also, I'd `clone()` the whole `tr` element initially and use it later on, instead of setting loops for each click.

---

```
// copy customer details to shipping
$('input.copy-input').on("change keyup paste", function () {
    $('input#' + this.id + "_ship").val($(this).val());
});

// add new product row on invoice
var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
$(".add-row").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table'); 
});

calculateTotal();

$('#invoice_table').on('change keyup paste', '.calculate', function() {
    updateTotals(this);
    calculateTotal();
});

function updateTotals(elem) {
    var tr = $(elem).closest('tr'),
        quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', tr).val(),
        price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', tr).val(),
        percent = $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val(),
        subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

    // CALCULATE DISCOUNT PERCENTAGE:
    if(percent && $.isNumeric(percent) && percent !== 0){
        subtotal = subtotal - ((parseInt(percent) / 100) * subtotal);
    }

    $('.calculate-sub', tr).val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
}

function calculateTotal(){
    var grandTotal = 0.0;
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    $('.calculate-sub').each(function(){
        grandTotal += parseFloat($(this).val()) ;
    }); 
    $('.invoice-sub-total').text(parseFloat(grandTotal ).toFixed(2) );  
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/) (**Note**, I have removed `id` attributes and added `[]` to the input fields names)

---

An example of how you could retrieve values sent to PHP
(Each iteration inside loop will be analogue to each `tr`):

```
foreach($_POST['invoice_product'] as $key => $value){
    $name = $value;
    $qty = $_POST['invoice_product_qty'][$key];
    $price = $_POST['invoice_product_price'][$key];
    $discount = $_POST['invoice_product_discount'][$key];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh thats excellent mate thanks! so with the name[] i can pass those all to PHP for example as separate products to be added? also the discount is it possible to do 10% and does 10% off or if i done just 10 would be £10 ? really appreciate your help mate really do. I need to do the VAT thing as well which is a percentage discount (this comes from a PHP define though so not sure how would pass that rate) maybe data-rate="<?php echo VAT_RATE ?>" and get the rate from the html data-rate="" ?

Comment: Oh the VAT will also either be included in the price, so in that case would show the included amount at 20% whatever we set, and if excluded would need to add it to the final total... your a star for helping me on this really!

Comment: I have made some changed, should i do a new fiddle with it all updated? if your able to still help that is.

Comment: I have done a new fiddle for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/4wnov586/ - I tried displaying discount but not really working and think broke the value // total thing as only updates when you do a discount. Also started new function for VAT. Once again thanks for your time, if i can crack this last bit ill be so happy :)

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/3/ (**please note** - when you deal with payments, better make sure you know 101% what you're doing. There's no place for improvisations. Make your app safe!) As for PHP, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oh its just for invoice generation to generate a PDF, wont be doing payments or anything :) super thanks so much for your help dude!!

Comment: Just for the record, you should put some validations on the fields. F.ex: check whether `discount` value is not lower that `price`, `price` is a number, `quantity` is a number, etc... I made only basic validation for `discount` as an example.

Comment: So sorry to be a pain, do you know best way I can do a condition to include vat or exclude from price. Like product price includes the VAT and also product price excludes vat and therefor adds it on? In config.php i set define('VAT_INCLUDE', true) and can pass it to data-vat-method="" returns as 1 or 0. - Think currently it add VAT to the price, would be cool if could add that condition so option to include or exclude if you know what i mean. And again thanks so much for this.

Comment: Sure, I know what you mean - you want me to code the whole app for free for you ;) Well, you're lucky, I'm in a good mood today - http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/4/

Comment: haha no done most of it already was just this bit i was stuck! your a diamond mate that's really helped me out! thanks so much!

Comment: Arthur, ive added an extra field and add what i think is right to add a shipping cost but getting a indexOf error, prob something simple. Any ideas why? http://jsfiddle.net/6y4wdf7g/8/ - promise last time ill bug you :)